# Trying to open a file in Ruby - Getting TypeError: can't convert String into Integer

Tags: ruby, file, types

Not sure whats going on here, or what could be the integer in this case. Here's the code:

```
def build_array_from_file(filename)
    contents = []
    File.read(File.expand_path('lib/project_euler/' + filename), 'r') do |file|
      while line = file.get
        contents << line
      end
    end
    contents
  end
```

filename is a string and I've checked to make sure the path comes up valid.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[File.read](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-read) has no second argument for mode nor block, that's [File.open](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-open):

```
contents_string = File.read(File.expand_path('lib/project_euler/' + filename))
```

Note that you can also write:

```
contents = File.open(path).lines # returns a lazy enumerator, keeps the file open
```

Or:

```
contents = File.readlines(path) # returns an array, the file is closed.
```

Comment: The problem is that `File.open(path).lines` will not automatically close the file returned. What you are looking for is `contents = File.open(path) { |file| file.lines }`.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira: you have a point that this keeps the file open. Note though that this is inevitable if you plan lazy access. Try your snippet, it should return `IOError: closed stream`, you cannot lazily read on a closed stream.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira `File.open(path, &:lines)`

Answer (score 1):

`File.read` doesn't need the mode `r` - you already request 'read' in `File.read`. The parameters fo `File.read` are - after the filename - the offset and length (that's why a integer was expected in the error message).

You may give the mode as `File.read(filename, :mode => 'r')` This may be usefull, if you need the mode `rb` or `r:utf-8` (but there is also a `encoding`-option).